# NA values in linear model in r

Tags: r, linear-model, missing-data

I have the following dataset:

```
desingmatrix <-read.csv("path of csv with data", sep=";", dec=".")
View(desingmatrix)# vision de los datos
```

[image]

Then I try to set up the model using:

```
> lm(y ~ w1 + w2 + w3 + w4,desingmatrix)
```

but I get this output:

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ w1 + w2 + w3 + w4, data = desingmatrix)



  Coefficients:
(Intercept)           w1           w2           w3           w4  
     11.787           NA       -2.188        2.087        4.500
```

What is the meaning of NA in coefficients w1? How the 'NA' values are treated in this case?

I try this:

```
lm(formula = y ~ w1 + w2 + w3 + w4, data = desingmatrix, na.action = na.exclude)
```

But I got the same result. Any idea please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`w1` is just a vector of 1s, which is exactly the same as the intercept `lm` uses, so in fact the design matrix used will be singular (ie two columns that are identical). Either remove `w1` from your analysis and use the intercept as the measure of `w1` or explicitly remove the fitting of the intercept with

`lm(formula = y ~ 0 + w1 + w2 + w3 + w4, data = desingmatrix)`

Edit: if you're fitting against all variables using `lm`, you can use the '.' shortcut:

`lm(formula = y ~ 0 + ., data = desingmatrix)`

will give the same result.

Comment: I would re-state your answer to "**if** `w1` is a vector of 1s...", because we haven't seen the whole dataset so we could only guess if the rest of values of `w1` are also 1s.